# Is there a way to get the length of a return value in the same line of code?

Tags: c#, arrays, return

I'm not sure if I worded that right but heres what I'm looking for.

I would like to do something like this:

```
string lastWord = words.Split(':')[splitResult.Length -1];
```

Is there any way to make that happen or must I store the array first?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

using `Linq`, [`LastOrDefault`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.lastordefault(v=vs.110).aspx) extention.

```
string lastword = words.Split(':').LastOrDefault();
```

> If I would use Split, wouldnt I be splitting it twice?

It Depends.

if you do below, yes you are splitting twice.

```
string lastWord = words.Split(':')[words.Split(':').Length -1];
```

and if you use temporary variable for splits then you need `Split` only once.

```
var splits =words.Split(':');
string lastWord = splits[splits.Length -1];
```

Comment: This definetly does the job thanks for that, but just out of curiosity, is there a way to do what I tried?

Comment: Not really, but if you want to win a bet then technically you can remove newlines and make it look like one expression:

`string lastWord = Task.Run(() => { var splits = words.Split(':'); return splits[splits.Length - 1]; }).Result;`

Comment: @AmadeuszWieczorek Agreed :-)

Comment: +1. That is **exactly** what I was looking for. I imagined it a little bit simpler though. Thanks a lot!